# Application of argument principle

Tags: complex-analysis

Do you have any idea to prove the following formula?

$\int_{-j \infty }^{+j \infty}  \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} dz = -\pi j (N_{Z} - N_{P})$

- $f(z)$ is a rational function
- $N_{P}$ is the number of poles in the right half plane.
- $N_{Z}$ is the number of zeros in the right half plane.

For a Jordan curve $C$ and a rational function $f(z)$, we obtain the following (the argument principle).

$\oint_{C} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz  = 2\pi j(Z-P)$

where $Z$ and $P$ are respectively, the number of zeros and poles of $f$ inside the region defined by $C$.

I guess the first formula is an application of the argument principle.

Comment: "j" is the imaginary unit. I use "j" instead of "i" because I am an electrical engineer.

Comment: If $f(z) = c\frac{\prod_{m=1}^M (z-b_m)^{d_m}}{\prod_{n=1}^N (z-a_n)^{e_n}}$ is a rational function then $\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} = \sum_{m=1}^M \frac{d_m}{z-b_m}-\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{e_n}{z-a_n}$. Thus it reduces to $\int_{-i\infty}^{i\infty} \log(z-A)dz= \lim_{x \to \infty} \log(\frac{ix-A}{-ix - A})$ which depends only on $\text{sign}(\Re(A))$. Finally use that $N+M+L = 0$ where $L$ is the order of the "zero at $\infty$". Otherwise, you can apply a Möbius transformation, or you can see the Riemann sphere as a compact Riemann surface, so you can apply the residue theorem directly.

Comment: Could you give me some more help? I think, we always obtain $ \rm{ lim}_{x \to \infty} log(\frac{jx-A}{-jx -A}) = log(-1) = j \pi $ regardless to $ \rm{sign}
 (\mathfrak{R}(A))$ . In addition, I can't understand $N + M + L = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose first that $p(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k z^k$  is a polynomial without zeros on the imaginary axis and let $\gamma(t):= R e^{\frac{\pi}{2}jt}$,  for $t\in[-1,1]$.

By argument principle,

$$\int_{jR}^{-jR} \frac{p'(z)}{p(z)} dz + \int_{\gamma} \frac{p'(z)}{p(z)} dz = 2\pi j Z, $$

where $Z$ is the number of zeros of $p$ inside the region defined by the semi-circle of radius $R$.
One has that

$$ \int_{\gamma} \frac{p'(z)}{p(z)} dz = 
  j\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{nR^{n}a_{n}e^{n\frac{\pi}{2}jt}+\cdots+Ra_{1}e^{\frac{\pi}{2}jt}}{R^{n}a_{n}e^{n\frac{\pi}{2}jt}+\cdots+a_{0}} dt
$$

Thus, by dominated convergence theorem
$$ \lim_{R\rightarrow \infty}\int_{\gamma} \frac{p'(z)}{p(z)} dz = j\frac{\pi}{2} \int_{-1}^{1} \lim_{R\rightarrow \infty} \frac{nR^{n}a_{n}e^{n\frac{\pi}{2}jt}+\cdots+Ra_{1}e^{\frac{\pi}{2}jt}}{R^{n}a_{n}e^{n\frac{\pi}{2}jt}+\cdots+a_{0}} dt = j\frac{\pi}{2} \int_{-1}^{1} n\,dt= jn\pi $$

Consequently,

$$ \int_{-j\infty}^{j\infty} \frac{p'(z)}{p(z)} dz = -(2\pi j Z-jn\pi)= (n-2Z)\pi j, $$

where $Z$ is now the number of zeros of $p$ in the open right half-plane.

(An alternative proof that does not use argument principle can be seen in [Mathematical Systems Theory I, Proposition 3.4.3](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=T_FbCz6Hei4C&lpg=PA300&dq=%22phase%20increasing%20property%22&pg=PA298#v=onepage&q&f=true))

For the case where $f=p/q\,$ is a rational function, note first that

$$ \int_{-j\infty}^{j\infty} \frac{p'(z)}{p(z)} dz =  (\ln |p(z)| + j\arg p(z))\, \vert_{-j\infty}^{j\infty} = j\lim_{\omega\rightarrow\infty} (\arg p(j\omega) - \arg p(-j\omega))$$

which implies that

$$\lim_{\omega\rightarrow\infty} (\arg p(j\omega) - \arg p(-j\omega)) = (n-2Z)\pi $$
Thus

$$
\begin{eqnarray} 
\int_{-j\infty}^{j\infty} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} dz  &=& 
j\lim_{\omega\rightarrow\infty} \left(\arg \frac{p(j\omega)}{q(j\omega)} - \arg \frac{p(-j\omega)}{q(-j\omega)}\right) \\ 
&=&  
j\lim_{\omega\rightarrow\infty} (\arg p(j\omega) - \arg p(-j\omega) - 
(\arg q(j\omega) - \arg q(-j\omega))) \\
&=& j\pi(n - 2N_Z - 2N_P - \deg(q))
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Comment: I am curious how you change the integrand from ${p'(z) \over p(z)}$ to $\log p(z)$ in the equation after the sentence starting "For the case..."

Comment: @copper.hat There was a typo. I believe now it is correct.

Comment: Thanks! The argument used for polynomials above can be applied more or less directly (with an algebraic simplification) to rational functions. Meaning there is no need to compute using a branch of $\log$.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks for pointing this. It is a nice way to avoid the computation with Log.

Comment: @shamisen Thank you for your answer. I think the last equation is $$j \ \lim_{\omega \to \infty} \{ (\arg \ p(j\omega) - \arg p(-j\omega)) - (\arg q(j\omega) - \arg q(-j\omega)) \} = j \pi \{ (\deg(p) - 2N_Z) - (\deg(q) - 2N_P)  \} = j \pi (\deg(p) - 2N_Z + 2N_P - \deg(q))$$ In my case, $\deg(p) = N_Z$ and $\deg(q) = N_P$. So the result is $$-j \pi (N_Z - N_P)$$ This is what I want.